# WCF MSMQ consumer thread count

Tags: .net, wcf, multithreading, msmq, consumer

What's the best way to configure the maximum number of threads that can pull messages from an MSMQ queue, using a netMsmqBinding in WCF?

For example, say I have an MSMQ service for which I only want to have 2 (or 10, or whatever number of) worker threads pulling messages off at a time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [Service Throttling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.servicemodel.description.servicethrottlingbehavior.aspx)

```
<behaviors>
 <serviceBehaviors>
  <behavior name="DefaultThrottlingBehavior">
   <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="2" />
  </behavior>
 </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```