# WCF - possible to switch between single-thread and multi-thread purely through config?

Tags: wcf, service, config, single-threaded

I have developed a WCF service (which happens to listen on an MSMQ queue). I haven't put any specific threading-related code in, so it runs by default in a multi-threaded manner. This will be fine (and most probably desirable) for a live environment, however right now this service is still being tested. I don't have total control over when messages appear on the test queue, so I'm in a situation where many could appear at once.

The service does a lot of diagnostic logging, but the logging mechanism I am obliged to use (the "company standard") is not thread-aware. So the upshot is that then several threads run at once my logging becomes a total mess. What I would like to do is to throttle the number of threads back to 1 while I am testing.

I have seen various ways of achieving single-threadedness in code, but I really don't fancy releasing one binary to Test and a different binary to Live.

I know that WCF is pretty hot on the use of config files so I was wondering whether there was some way, based purely in config, of telling a WCF service whether to listen in a single-threaded or multi-threaded mode?

TIA,
Pete

Comment: I think I had a similar question awhile ago, this might have some useful info:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767140/wcf-msmq-consumer-thread-count

Comment: Andy, thats exactly what I'm looking for I think.

Comment: yeah, sorted. If you want to propose this as the answer then I'll tick it and you can get the points....like you need 'em!!!

Comment: Cool, I'm glad that was what you needed.  I put an answer down just for the heck of it!  +1 for your question too, since I had the exact same question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this question:  [WCF MSMQ consumer thread count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767140/wcf-msmq-consumer-thread-count)

Glad this helped!

Answer (score 1):

You could place all of the code within the service, inside a wrapper class that a Dependency Injection framework could inject at runtime.

With Dependency Injection you can configure whether to implement the dependency as a singleton, or as a per request instance.

However, testing the app in "single threaded mode" will not be sufficient.

Alternatively, why not include the current executing threadid in the logging info - then filter the logfile by threadid as required?

Comment: second point first - the log file does contain the thread id, however each logfile entry spans many lines. This is an implementation of Enterprise logging from about 5 years back. So, filtering would be pretty difficult.

Comment: first point second - that seems like a mighty big sledgehammer to crack my tiny walnut. I can see where you're coming from but I can't help wondering whether this is the optimum approach to take,

Comment: I agree - if you have not used DI, then it is a big sledgehammer - but I would advocate this approach over building your own singleton and using it or not using it depending on the value of a config value. Personally I'd try and sort out the main issue, which is the readability of log files - you are likely to need to debug the app in multi-threaded mode at some point, at which point you'll have the same issue.

Comment: Bony, thanks for this but as I said in my original post I don't have any option other than to use the logging mechanism I'm given. That's just the way it is.